# How to turn a Function into a Dialog Box in Bluesky Statistics Dialog Designer

Tags: python, r

I am very new to BlueSky, I've never used it before and no one at my job knows how to use it. I was hoping someone could explain to me how I must go about turning a function into a dialog box. I don't have any idea how Bluesky even works, as I've never worked with anything like it. I can also provide the function I need to turn into the dialog box if needed (the function was created in R programming).

Once again, I am a rookie at this, and the more detailed the help, the better. For more help, I have coded in Python and R before but I am not fluent in them.

Thank you!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. We can't give you detailed help without seeing any details on your end

Answer (score 0):

Check the video gallery at https://www.blueskystatistics.com/category-s/109.htm

The specific videos you should watch are

Series 1: Using dialog editor to create dialogs and richly formatted output with BlueSky Statistics
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43jw719Twx0&feature=youtu.be

Series 2(Part A): Creating more sophisticated dialogs with BlueSky Statistics
https://youtu.be/JZSJm0hQHH4

Series 2(Part B): Creating more sophisticated dialogs with BlueSky Statistics
https://youtu.be/qp8JzXY5PA0

Series 3:Creating a dialog for a data manipulation command with BlueSky Statistics
https://youtu.be/UG59NW9LFJI

Series 4: Creating a dialog for a graphics command with BlueSky Statistics
https://youtu.be/XPpcQDb3yWM